# set column name of a table for file name in php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

> set column name of a table for file name in php
>
> this is my code it is creating file named as "SELECT Name_of_company FROM companyinformation WHERE id="$id" in my folder".

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
session_start();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql='
SELECT Name_of_company 
  FROM companyinformation 
 WHERE id="$id"
';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $sql;


$createfile=$rows.".txt";

$email=$_SESSION['coll'];
$rnumber=$_SESSION['roll_number'];
$rollnumber="Roll Number \n";
$Email="Email Address ";
$newline="\n";
$rollema=$Email.$rollnumber;

$myfile = fopen($createfile, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $email);
fwrite($myfile," ");
fwrite($myfile, $rnumber);
fwrite($myfile, $newline);
fclose($myfile);
//echo "<script>alert('Register Successfully');window.open('studentloginpage.php','_self');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: @Dave I want to create a file name with column name of table

Comment: @Dave: I think the question is "Why isn't this code working?". (NOTE: the pattern in the code appears to vulnerable to SQL Injection.)

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 ... you saw it but I didn't.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: In PHP only double-quoted strings are interpolated. Single quoted strings are not.

Comment: @tadman: Good catch. I stand corrected, the code is not vulnerable to SQL Injection... since the SQL text is a string literal, with no interpolation. (Once OP fixes it, it will be vulnerable.)

Comment: This is a failed SQL injection, but the intent was to inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_array returns an array  (or FALSE if there isn't a row.)

Each entry in the array contains the value for a single column in the resultset (for the one row that was fetched).

Reference the element of the array, by the name of the column.

```
$createfile = $rows['Name_of_company'].".txt";
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, consider testing the return

```
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if(! $rows) {
   // we got a row, continue processing
   ...
} else {
   // no row fetched
   ...
}
```

(Also, `$rows` is plural. It's just a variable name, we could name it `$fargedlybarp` or whatever. But I would tend to make the name singular e.g. (`$row`) rather than plural, to indicate to the future reader that we expect this to contain a single row.)

```
if( ! $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
   // we got a row, continue processing
   ... 
} else {
   // no row fetched
   ...
}
```

**FOLLOWUP**

As @tadman points out, there is no interpolation here:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name_of_company FROM companyinformation WHERE id="$id"';
```

The single quotes is a string literal, that doesn't do any variable interpretation.

Likely, we wanted the value of the `$id` variable to be incorporated into the SQL text.  If that's an integer value, then we can do this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name_of_company FROM companyinformation WHERE id='''
     . intval( $id ) 
     . '''' ;
```

Otherwise, the value of `$id` needs to be properly escaped

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name_of_company FROM companyinformation WHERE id='''
     . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $id )
     . '''' ;
```

As @tadman also recommends, using *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders* is best practice pattern.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name_of_company FROM companyinformation WHERE id = ?';
```

and prepare, bind_param, execute, ...

Comment: Since you're using the clumsy `intval(...)` method of conversion you will get an integer and you don't need quotes. The escaping version is ong-winded and messy. The placeholder version is the actual answer here, it's safer, easier to read, and as a bonus, if you're doing this statement multiple times you can prepare once, repeatedly execute.

Comment: @tadman: all good points.  Yes, our first preference to parameterized queries (prepared statements with bind placeholders), If we don't do that, then at a bare minimum, values need to be properly escaped before including them in the SQL text.  I'm not going to avoid long-winded, at the expense of SQL Injection vulnerabilities. And yes, `intval` is the cludgiest of fixes.

Comment: What I mostly mean is that your last code snippet should be your first. The others are more academic explanation which, while valuable, shouldn't be the first thing someone tries.